# Customize \ref command

Tags: hyperref, numbering, fontsize

Is there anyway to customize the number which appear in a `\ref{}` command? More precisely,  I want to reduce the size of such number but without affecting the number font (style). If I use a command like `\small` before a `\ref{}`, the number font does not still the same (see for instance the two photos).

[image: result with the \small command]

[image: result without the \small command]

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=auto, version=last, chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{charter}

\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm} blablabla. \end{theorem}

{\small theorem~\ref{thm}}\\

theorem~\ref{thm}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you enclose `\small` within parenthesis? For example `{\small\ref{cor:something}}`. Note there are some settings which you should be able to define to better suite your needs. Please also post a MWE (minimal working example) so that one can better assist you.

Comment: Try `theorem~{\small\ref{thm}}`

Comment: Your example doesn't show the behaviour of your picture. The font used in your picture is a sans serif font like `cmss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an alternative to do what I want. It consist of the use of commands `\normalfont` before the `\tiny` command:

```
\stackrel{\mathclap{\normalfont\mbox{\tiny formule~\ref{e2}}}}{=}
```

and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

To automate the use of the `\small` font size directive for all instances of `\ref`, you could issue the following commands in your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\ref}{\bgroup\small}{}{}
\apptocmd{\ref}{\egroup}{}{}
```

The commands `\bgroup` and `\egroup` serve to form an explicit TeX "group", so that the scope of the command `\small` ends after `\ref` has done its job.

If you load the `babel` package as well (at least with the `frenchb` language option -- I haven't checked it with other language options...), be sure to insert the code given above *before* loading the `babel` pacakge.

The following example builds on your MWE. For the sake of making the effect of the font size change immediately obvious, I use `\tiny` rather than `\small` for the example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, pagesize=auto, version=last, 
   chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\ref}{\bgroup\tiny}{}{} % be sure to execute these commands before loading "babel"
\apptocmd{\ref}{\egroup}{}{}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm} blablabla. \end{theorem}

{\tiny Th\'eor\`eme~\ref{thm}}

Th\'eor\`eme~\ref{thm}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. (However, I noticed that the \small command does not affect the number font if I use \eqref)

Comment: There is no error or warning message. I want to obtain only the result when using \ref.

Comment: @user42450 - I've added an MWE to illustrate how the code should be used. To make the effect of the font size change more dramatically self-evident, I used `\tiny` rather than `\small` for the example.

Comment: Sorry, I follow what you propose and the number font still changes. I think there is a problem in my main document (perhaps a boring package or command)...